# Does Cassandra inet type support CIDR querying?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

Firstly, is the INET in vanilla Cassandra or only in Datastax's version?

If it is available in vanilla Cassandra does it support CIDR queries?

Everything I've been able to find says its just a string representation of either IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InetAddress is supported in Apache cassandra. It's implementation is at https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/InetAddressType.java

It does not, as far as I can tell, support querying or matching via CIDR.